# JQuery MouseEnter - Trigger only for element that has not specific class

Tags: jquery, mouseenter

I use mouseenter on a class but if that class has another class the mouseenter method should not be triggered. I tired the below code but for some reason I do not get it is not working. Any ideas why and maybe some suggestions?

```
$(".someClass:not('.someOtherClass')").mouseenter(function(){ 
    //some code
});
```

Comment: Its working for me in this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4edkT/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This piece of code triggers on enter of someClass
If the mouse does not have a class of someOtherClass it will execute the //do this code.

```
 $(".someClass").mouseenter(function(e){ 
     if (!$(e.target).hasClass('someOtherClass')){
         // do this
     }
 });
```